# How do I undo rating a show on Crunchyroll?

Tags: crunchyroll

I accidentally rated a show on Crunchyroll before watching the series. How do I remove my rating?

[image: Accidental 4 star rating for 'Shine on! Bakumatsu Bad Boys']

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to remove a rating on Crunchyroll. Once a show has been rated, your only option is to submit a different rating.